# Loader progress takes only 0 or 1 value

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2

I'm loading the `Game.qml` component using `Loader` and it works fine. However the `onProgressChanged` slot is called only once - at the end of the process (when `progress` takes value `1`).

```
GameWindow {

    ...

    Loader {
        id: loader
        onLoaded: if(item) splashScene.state = "hidden"
        onProgressChanged: splashScene.progress = progress
    }

    SplashScene {
        id: splashScene
        state: "shown"
    }

    Timer {
        id: lateInitializer
        interval: 1000
        onTriggered: loader.source = "Game.qml"
    }

    Component.onCompleted: lateInitializer.start()
}
```

Is there any way to cooperate with `Loader` from `GameWindow` or `Game` component?

EDIT: Here's my splash scene:

```
MyScene {
    id:scene

    property alias progress: progressBar.progress

    ...

    MyProgressBar {
        id: progressBar

        anchors {
            horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            bottom: parent.bottom
            bottomMargin: parent.height/3 - height/2
        }
    }
}
```

I don't use anything special. I just want to animate my progress bar.

Comment: Are you noticing a UI slowdown? Or what's exactly the problem? If `Game.qml` is small and fast to load, why would it be wrong for progress to jump to 1?

Comment: Progress always jumps from 0 to 1, no matter how long the loading time is. However, thanks to your comment, I can see that if I put an animation to the splash screen it always hangs after one second of loading. This freeze lasts until Loader is finished.

Comment: how is your `progress`  property defined in `SplashScene` ?

Comment: `property real progress: 0`

Answer (score 1):

As from the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html#progress-prop):

> This property holds the progress of loading QML data from the network, from 0.0 (nothing loaded) to 1.0 (finished). Most QML files are quite small, so this value will rapidly change from 0 to 1.

I'd add that it's perfectly normal for it to be incredibly fast, thus to step from 0 to 1, in cases when the file is loaded from the local disk.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the `asynchronous: true` property to your `Loader` component. This property allows you to "listen" on a status change.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html#asynchronous-prop

**Edit:**
You can react on status change like this:

```
Loader {
   visible: status == Loader.Ready
}
```

So for your case you can maybe create the following:

```
Loader {
    id: loader
    onStatusChanged: splashScene.progress = status
}

SplashScene {
    id: splashScene
    state: loader.status === Loader.Ready ? "shown" : undefined
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I overlooked this parameter. However the main problem is still not solved.

Comment: See my edits. Maybe you have to provide some more code because I miss your `SplashScene` implementation.